# Fedora command line install eclipse with android sdk

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, fedora, yum

I am a new Fedora user (having previously always used ubuntu), and I am trying to download eclipse. Unfortunately, "sudo yum install eclipse" is returning "no package eclipse available". I assume this means that I am missing the correct repo, but I can't seem to find the right one / how to add it to my repo list for this version. My version of fedora is centos5 based, and my current repo list is the following:

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
repo id                 repo name                                         status
amzn                    amzn-v0.9-Base                                     2,041
rpmforge                RHEL 2010.11 - RPMforge.net - dag                 10,733
repolist: 12,774
```

I am doing all of this just for the sake of being able to build android applications from the command line. As far as I understand, running tools/android update sdk requires eclipse (since it is currently giving me an error complaining that eclipse is missing) That said, I am perfectly happy to not install eclipse, if there is a way around it.

The error I am getting from /tools/android update sdk is:

```
No command line parameters provided, launching UI.
See 'android --help' for operations from the command line.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3550 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showMainWindow(Main.java:297)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:265)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:99)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:88)
```

Thanks in advance for any input anyone has!

Regards

Avtar

Comment: To format the code sample, just select it in the editor and press the button on top of text edit area with `{}` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Download Eclipse from here:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads

You will get a fresher version than from Linux repo.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is available on RPMFusion[1], so it'd be great if you install RPMFusion repo (they come in two versions: Free and non-free. I highly recommend installing both)

[1] http://rpm.pbone.net